# removes the first element in an array without using shift() method

Tags: javascript, arrays

In my software engineering boot camp prep course I was asked to write a a JavaScript function that removes the first value in an array and returns the value of the removed element without using the built-in shift method.

It should return `undefined` if the array is empty. My code looks like below, but it does not pass all the tests.

```js
function shift(arr) {
    let arr1 = [];
    arr1 = arr.splice(0, 1);
    if (arr.length > 0) {
        return arr1;
    }
    return "undefined";
}
```

Comment: Are you sure you are supposed to return a string and not `undefined` if the array is empty?

Comment: Also `arr1` is an array, but your requirement seems to be to return a single element, so that would be `arr1[0]`

Comment: Also you should check whether `arr` is empty *before* you try and splice a value out of it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Sounds like a good use case for the Array.splice method.
Give it a read [here](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/splice).

This should be the solution you're looking for

```
function myShift(arr) {
    if (!arr || arr.length === 0) return undefined;
    return arr.splice(0, 1);
}
```

If the array passed to the method is falsy (null/undefined), or if it has 0 elements, return undefined.
The splice method will return the elements removed from the array.
Since you remove 1 element from the 0th index, it will return that element (and also mutate the original array).

Answer (score 4):

You could use destructing assignment combined with spread operator

```js
const arr = [1, 2, 3]

const [removed, ...newArr] = arr

console.log(removed)
console.log(newArr)
```

---

#### Reference

[Destructuring assignment](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Destructuring_assignment)

[Spread syntax (...)](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Spread_syntax)

Comment: This does not give the same result as `splice` though. I think the OP wants to mutate the original array.

Answer (score 0):

I have altered your code.

1. If no data is present in the array return undefined.
2. If yes, return the first value by splice method.

```js
function shift(arr) {
    if(!arr.length){
      return undefined;
    }
    arr1 = arr.splice(0, 1);
   return arr1
   }

var arr = [12,14,156];
console.log(shift(arr));
```